# Update Blazor Component Div in JS function

Tags: blazor

I am new to Blazor and JS. I am using VS2022 preview.

I have created a Blazor component that uses [`OpenLayers`](https://openlayers.org/) to display a map.
The user can enter X and Y and then click a button to display the map.
Everything works fine the first time, but each button click after adds an additional new map to the div (i.e. 3 clicks equals 3 maps). I want the function to replace the existing map in the div with a new map.
My best case scenario would be to get the existing map (if it exists) and just update the view - but for now just replacing the existing map will do.

Here is the blazor:

```
@page "/map"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
```

... html for input, button, etc.

```cs
@code {
    private MapJsInterop js;

    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "My Map";
    [Parameter]
    public double X { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public double Y { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        js = new(JS);
    }

    private void DisplayMap()
    {
        js.DisplayMap(X, Y);
    }

    public void Dispose() => js?.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Here is the DisplayMap c# method:

```cs
    public async void DisplayMap(double x, double y)
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("displayMap", x, y);
    }
```

Here is the JS function that creates the map:

```js
export function displayMap(x, y) {
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([x, y]),
            zoom: 16
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: `public async void ` NEVER do this. You're creating a task and then throwing it away. Always use `public async Task`

Comment: Where are those `DisplayMap` methods called from? Is `js.DisplayMap` the `async void` one? In that case *all* of them should return a `Task` and be awaited. Only event handlers called from HTML need no awaiting. The HTML is missing, so we can't guess what else is missing

Comment: In any case, what's the problem? The question contains incomplete code with some obvious problems, but what's the actual problem?

Comment: @enet the problem is the answers, not Henk Holterman. The *question* you linked to makes little sense. And the answer .... no, you don't need to use all that code just to call a Javascript method from Blazor. Just a `JS.InvokeAsync` with the method name and the parameters *as an object*. You definitely don't need so much code to display a map

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, do you mean that what I was illustrating in my code snippet can be simplified to "Just a JS.InvokeAsync with the method name and the parameters as an object." I'll be grateful to you, and hold you in high esteem, if you can take my code and improve on it, so as to reflect your claims. After all you're a developer, I'm not.

Comment: @enet I mean that the code needed to call one Javascript library has little to offer when calling an *unrelated* library. I mean that instead of blaming others, you should improve your answers

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm new to all this. I am going by what's in the C# template for Blazor component library and all that template code is how it seems to be calling custom JS functions.

I have a html div (id="map") that I want to update with an OpenLayers map. I got the js map function from the OpenLayers example.

What I want to do is update the div with the new map when the user clicks the button.
How would you call the js map function?

    private void DisplayMap()
    {
        //what code goes here to call the DisplayMap JS function?
    }

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get this to work. I changed my displayMap function to use  a 'window.' variable to store the map:

```
export function displayMap(x, y) {
    if (window.divMap == null) {
        window.divMap = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ]
        });
    }

    window.divMap.setView(
        new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([x, y]),
            zoom: 16
        })
    );
}
```

Now when the user clicks the button either a new map is created or the existing map is updated with the new view.
I don't know if this is good way to do this, but it does work.
Feel free to post an example if you think there is a better way.
Thanks.